# Modifying wordcount source code: hadoop example. How to change delimiter to be ".", "," or " "?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am new to hadoop and java. I am using Hadoop 2.X and trying to change the wordcount source code so that when I run wordcount on text, it considers ".", "," or " " delimiters at the same time, and not just "\t". I found that changing the configuration using this:

```
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", " ");
```

but even changing the delimiter to "," alone is not working. The code runs without crashing but I get the same result as if I was running wordcount with the default delimiter "\t".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the correct place. You do not need to change the source code: just add command line arg

```
bin/hadoop job -Dkey.value.separator.in.input.line=,
```

Notice the property name has changed.

Also it may not support multiple delimiters that you are looking for.

You can find more info here http://www.feeny.org/changing-keyvalue-split-delimeter-in-hadoop-20-2/

**UPDATE**

Here is source you might change

```
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

22         String line = value.toString();
  23         StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line,"., ");

Comment: Could I instead of changing the config, change the WordCount class? StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ".,[]"); The only problem is that I tried this one as well and it did not work...

Comment: sounds like a reasonable approach.  i will look into  the source as well

Comment: Updated my post.  But it looks like you already are trying the same thing.

Comment: I keep getting the result as if I had not changed my delimiter at all! What am I doing wrong? I am using Text key instead of LongWritable key... could that be the problem?